# How to make a self-adjusting two-way concatenation table?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

My question is best portrayed in the picture below. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: That is an unusual question. If you are not satisfied with the answers so far, please describe your _end goal_. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, see the [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oXGcM4GaZ5MSon9bdqATks7RZDCdt_uqznY5S7Kdqp4/edit?usp=sharing)

A4 contains following formula:

```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(
  TRANSPOSE(
   FILTER(
    TRANSPOSE(
     FILTER($A$1:$F$1&TRANSPOSE($A$1:$F$1),$A$2:$F$2)
   ),$A$2:$F$2)
  )
 )
```

The idea is to FILTER() data columns based on checkmarks, then transpose result and again FILTER() rows now and transpose the result.

Comment: I upvoted your solution :) ... but `arrayformula()` is not needed, while it's better to add an `ifna()` function to avoid errors when there are no checkboxes checked, like this: `=ifna(transpose(filter(transpose(filter(A1:F1&transpose(A1:F1),A2:F2)),A2:F2)))`

Comment: @Daniele you are right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in cell `C5`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    transpose(C2:G2) * C2:G2, 
    transpose(C1:G1) & C1:G1, 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

It uses the values in `C1:G1` and the checkboxes in `C2:G2` to create the first 5x5 grid.

To also filter the headers the way shown in the second and third grid, put this formula in cell `B4`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    if( 
      B2:G2, 
      B1:G1, 
      iferror(1/0) 
    ); 
    if( 
      transpose(C2:G2), 
      transpose(C1:G1), 
      iferror(1/0) 
    ), 
    if( 
      transpose(C2:G2) * C2:G2, 
      transpose(C1:G1) & C1:G1, 
      iferror(1/0) 
    ) 
  } 
)
```